# Removing the Name button in the address bar

Tags: php, html

When I try to do
Search in Form
i get in address bar the following entry

> check.php?go_btn=&s=banana

Why do I get the name of the button "go_btn"
I should get the value

> check.php?s=banana

Why this value

> name = "go_btn"

Appears in the address bar

**simple_search.html**

```
<form action="check.php" method="get" id="my_form"> 
<input name="go_btn" type="submit" id="go_btn" form="my_form" formaction="check.php" 
formmethod="get"
style="background-image: url(images/go.png); border: solid 0px #000000; width: 
71px; height: 55px;" value="">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s">
</form>
```

**check.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['go_btn'])) {
$s_find = $_GET['s'];
if ($s_find == "banana") {
print ("you find banana");
 }
else {
print ("blablabla....");
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: `<input name="go_btn"` thats why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, In your PHP instead of asking about `go_btn` ask for `s` as follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
   $s_find = $_GET['s'];
   if ($s_find == "banana") {
      print ("you find banana");
   }
   else{
      print ("blablabla....");
   }
}
?>
```

And then remove the attribute name from your form's element `go_btn` as follows:

```
<form action="check.php" method="get" id="my_form"> 
<input type="submit" id="go_btn" form="my_form" formaction="check.php" 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You get it because you asked for it:

```
<input name="go_btn" [..snip...] value="" />
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any `<input>` field with a `name` attribute will get submitted along with the rest of the form. If you don't want `go_btn` being submitted, then take away the `name` attribute.

Comment: I tried to delete this but the PHP file can not check the value sent

Answer (score 0):

You will get it because you asked for it. Your form method is `GET` and the `GET` method takes all values with it in the URL. If you would like not to see those values in the URL, you may use the `POST` method.

Moreover, you shouldn't be having ANY problem with that term in the URL, simple because you need that variable in the other file.